# How to loop a query every second in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that automatically generates content for my app. I want to execute it as many times as possible because the stuff it generates can be generated every second (I don't care for amounts less than a second). This query is based on some information in the DB and depending on how much data it will generate it might take more than a second. That is not a problem, but in that case as soon as it finishes it should run again.

I am currently using a job, and it's scheduled to run as many times in a 10 second interval(min allowed by sql server). The problem is that because of this loop it will run for more than 10 seconds which will cause the next run of the job to be skipped.

How can I reduce the time of the job from 10s to 1s, but keeping the same functionality that SQL Server has for a job.

TL;DR I want to create a job that runs every 1 sec and skips rounds if the previous one took too long.

Comment: How intensive is the processing - Can you use triggers?

Comment: If this isn't an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) I don't know what is. I am roughly 99.99999% certain a better approach than what you are trying to do here is available.

Comment: @DanielTranca . . . This seems like a really bad idea.  The database might spend so much time fetching the data you want that it doesn't have spare cycles to do anything else.  Why doesn't your application just use the query to fetch the data?

Comment: I don't need to fetch anything. I only need to spawn random items based on another table. The other table has options to go as often as every second.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WAITFOR  function

example :

```
BEGIN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
EXECUTE sp_helpdb;
END;
GO
```

Comment: I don't think that an endless loop with waitfor is really a very good solution. But I suppose it would mostly deal with the issue they are having.

Comment: this is not good. I don't want to wait for anytime if the query took more than 1 sec. In your example if the query took 3.4s it'll wait 2 more seconds which is kinda inconvenient since I want to execute it every second

Comment: @DanielTranca - so you would need to record the time before the action and after it. and if less than a second elapsed time wait for the difference between that and a second. I doubt I would ever want to do this though

Comment: @MartinSmith I did that, but the problem is that the last loop might be longer than the remaining time of it's schedule meaning that the job will skip the next one which causes me more problems than solving